# Send encrypted email with attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, encryption, email-attachments

This seems like a tough one to find a good answer to. I want to create a mail message, add attachments to it, encrypt it using a X509Certificate2 certificate, and then send it. Sounds simple enough, right?! I use asp.net mvc and C#.

This is what I have so far.

```
string sMTPClient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPClient");
        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(sMTPClient))
        {
            var attachments = MethodToCreateMailAttachments(......);
            X509Certificate2 certificate = MethodToGetCertificateBySerialNumber("xxxxxxx");

            using (var finalMailmessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                var encryptedMailMessage = new MailMessage();
                var encryptCert = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
                encryptedMailMessage.Subject = mailsubject;
                encryptedMailMessage.Body = mailBody;
                if (attachments.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in attachments)
                        encryptedMailMessage.Attachments.Add(item);
                }

                byte[] encryptedBodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedMailMessage.ToString());

                EnvelopedCms Envelope = new EnvelopedCms(new ContentInfo(encryptedBodyBytes));
                CmsRecipient Recipient = new CmsRecipient(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, encryptCert);
                Envelope.Encrypt(Recipient);
                byte[] EncryptedBytes = Envelope.Encode();

                //Attach the encrypted message as an alternate view.
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(EncryptedBytes);
                AlternateView av = new AlternateView(ms, "application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data;name=smime.p7m");
                finalMailmessage.AlternateViews.Add(av);

                finalMailmessage.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom);

                foreach (var address in mailTo.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    finalMailmessage.To.Add(address);
                }

                var smtp = new SmtpClient(sMTPClient);
                smtp.Send(finalMailmessage);
                finalMailmessage.Dispose();
                ErrorLogging.log.Debug("Mailmessage sent");
                return "";
            }
        }
```

What this does is create two MailMessages, one for the things that need to be encrypted, attachments, body and subject.  Then I create the message that will be sent. To this I add the first message as an alternate view. This works so far as to encrypt and send the email, and on the recieving end, I get an email with a padlock icon in Outlook.

I can then open the message in Outlook, by importing the certificate. This works. However, next to the padlock icon, in Outlook, I get the attachment paperclip icon, which suggests that there is something attached to the message. But the message is empty. So nothing gets attached apparently. I suspect the adding of the encrypted MailMessage as an alternate view to the other MailMessage, is where I have gone wrong.

I've tried a lot of other things with no luck, and this is the closest I have come to a working solution. I need some input, so does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What's behind the 'MethodToCreateMailAttachments' method?

Comment: It only creates a List of attachment objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution. The problem was this part:

```
byte[] encryptedBodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedMailMessage.ToString());
```

I had to create a memorystream, which can then be converted into a byte array. I used a tool called "MimeKit", which can be installed as a nuget package.

So, instead I have:

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
var mimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(encryptedMailMessage);
mimeMessage.WriteTo(memStream);
var messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
byte[] encryptedBodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString);
```

The rest is the same.

Comment: Great. You can mark your answer (with the 'green tick') as the one that solved your problem, so that can help other people in the future having the same issue.

Comment: I would like to, except when I try, I get "You can accept your own answer tomorrow", which is... meh...